# How to change multiple inputs in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I wanna make quiz using html/js and I don't know how to change values in the form to add more questions and move between them, now it's very simple:

HTML:

```
<form name="quiz">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1"><br>
</form>
    <button onclick="submitAnswers()">Check Answer</button>
```

JS:

```
const answers = ["b","a"];

function submitAnswers() {
    let q1 = document.forms["quiz"]["q1"].value;
    if (q1 == answers[0]) {
        console.log('Correct answer');
    } else {
        console.log('Incorrect answer');
    }
}
```

And I want to make a navigation buttons so I can move to next or previous question and buttons with numbers so I can jump between the questions, and I want it to save the answer, so for example if I check answer in question 1 and move to question 15, I can move back to question 1 and have the answer selected, but I don't have any idea how to to start and make any of these...

Any hints?

Comment: You cannot have different elements with the same id. Nor can you have multiple items selected with a radio

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the forms input elements with `formData` then loop over its entries, store the answers in a object.

HTML

```
<form id="quiz">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" id="a" name="q1" value="a">
      A
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" id="b" name="q1" value="b">
      B
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" id="c" name="q1" value="c">
      C
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" id="d" name="q1" value="d">
      D
    </label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Check Answer</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
const form = document.getElementById('quiz');
const answers = {
  'q1': ["b","a"],
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    // pair[0] is the input name, pair[1] is the value.
    if (answers[pair[0]].includes(pair[1])) {
      console.log('correct')
    } else {
      console.log('incorrect')
    }
  } 
})
```

Comment: Radio buttons cannot have multiple values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: @Steve hes not after multiple values, hes after one. radio is singular value, checkbox otherwise, His answers can be 1 or the other. Not both hence the includes.